# How to join 2 different assertions in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, assertion, chaining

guys.
Do you know how to join 2 different assertions?

```
  assert.isNotNull(res.body, "is not null");
  assert.isNotNull(res.body.createdAt, "is not null");
```

ref:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your assertion in a `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all([
  assert.isNotNull(res.body, "is not null"),
  assert.isNotNull(res.body.createdAt, "is not null")
])
```

You pass an array of assertions.  Both will have to pass in order to pass the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `expect` chai assertion along with `&&`, something like:

```js
expect(res.body).to.not.be.null && expect(res.body.createdAt).to.not.be.null
```